# lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

while compiling it i m getting errors 
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment      fac(0)=1;
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment      fac(i)=i*fac(i-1);

```
#include<stdio.h>


int fac(int i)


{

    int j;

    fac(0)=1;

    fac(i)=i*fac(i-1);


    printf("%d",fac(i));


}

int main()
{

    int x,y;

    printf("enter the number");

    scanf("%d",&x);

    if(x>=0)

    {
        fac(x);
    }


}
```

Comment: `fac(0)=1;` Really? Where did you started to learn `C` ?

Answer (score 2):

In C, you do not return a function value that way; instead, you would write something like

```
 if ( i == 1 || i == 0 )
   return 1;

 return i * fac(i - 1);
```

The problem is that the *result* of `fac(0)` does not refer to an *object* that you can write to; it's like trying to assign a new value to `1` - you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
fac(0)=1;
```

is not valid c, you don't assign a value for recursion like that.

it seems like you'd want something closer to

```
if(j==0) {
  return 1;
}


fac(i)=i*fac(i-1);
```

Same here you can't assign a value to `fac(i)` because it is a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
fac(0)=1;
```

Here `fac` is a function. `fac(0)` will return some value (say x). You cannot then assign that returned value to be 1. Not in C at least.

What you are trying to do is to set the function to return 1 when the input is 0.

This can be achieved by

```
int fac(int i)
{
  int j;
  if (i == 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  { 
    return (i*fac(i-1));
  }
  printf("%d",fac(i));
}
```

Comment: Note that the `printf` statement will never be executed in this code.